# Localization of Application Bar in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want localize my App Bar which I have made in app.xaml but when i try to bind the text of the bar item it says text cannot be empty , i have tried other examples of localized app bar but none of them is working for a app bar which can be used on all pages..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can declare a global app bar in `App.xaml` with some fake `Text`, for example:

```
<Application
    x:Class="PhoneApp1.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">

    <!--Application Resources-->
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhoneApp1" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="GlobalAppBar">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="TEST" IconUri="/Assets/check.png"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </Application.Resources>

    <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
        <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
        <shell:PhoneApplicationService
            Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing"
            Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
    </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>

</Application>
```

In `App.xaml.cs` apply localization:

```
    var appBar = App.Current.Resources["GlobalAppBar"] as ApplicationBar;
    ((ApplicationBarIconButton) appBar.Buttons[0]).Text = AppResources.AppBarButtonText;
```

Now you can use the global `AppBar` everywhere in the `App`, just do initializing  in a code behind of a `PhoneApplicationPage`:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ApplicationBar = App.Current.Resources["GlobalAppBar"] as ApplicationBar;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error you're getting comes from the fact that the ApplicationBar is not a DependencyObject so it doesn't support Bindings. A common alternative is to use custom AppBar with DependencyProperties, most notably [BindableApplicationBar](http://bindableapplicationb.codeplex.com/)..

```
<bar:BindableApplicationBarButton
    Text="{Binding IconButtonText}"
    IconUri="{Binding IconUri, FallbackValue=/Icons/Dark/appbar.add.rest.png}"
    IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonIsEnabled}" />
```

or [CaliburnBindableAppBar](https://github.com/kamranayub/CaliburnBindableAppBar):

```
<bab:BindableAppBarButton
    x:Name="Add"
    Text="{Binding AddButtonText}"
    Visibility="{Binding ShowAddButton, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
    IconUri="{Binding ButtonIconUri}"/>
```

(.xaml samples from documentations)

Comment: thanx for your answer but i have resolved this issue by following above answer...

Comment: @SandeepChauhan I'm well aware, the answer is accepted - somebody else may face the same problem and could use this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could go the way the default VS template suggests:

1. Add the following code to your page's XAML (they say as the last element, but i'm not sure it matters)
2. Create a private method in the code behind to add and databind menu items and call it from the constructor (or wherever you're calling `InitializeComponent`):

XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" Mode="Minimized" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

C# code behind:

```
private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
{
    // Create a new menu item with the localized string from AppResources.
    ApplicationBarMenuItem appBarMenuItem = new ApplicationBarMenuItem(AppResources.AboutMenuItem);
    ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(appBarMenuItem);
}
```

Still not an ideal solution, but might be better than referencing non-native components just for such a trivial reason.

A couple of official references a combination of which might be useful as a reference in solving the problem:

- How to create an app bar using XAML for Windows Phone - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394040(v=vs.105).aspx
- How to create an app bar using code for Windows Phone - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431786(v=vs.105).aspx
- How to build a localized app for Windows Phone - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520(v=vs.105).aspx